# Why STATS_CROSSTAB CHISQ_SIG doesn't return correct p value in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table like below

```
    FLAG    RANDOM_GROUP    count
      CTR          1    53
      CTR          2    41
      CTR          3    43
      CTR          4    47
      CTR          5    45
      TRT          1    61
      TRT          2    42
      TRT          3    49
      TRT          4    42
      TRT          5    41
```

I'm using STATS_CROSSTAB(random_group,flag, 'CHISQ_SIG') but it returns p_value is 1. Since the count column in this table was calculated based on random number generated for each run, I cannot repeat each row "Count" times.

Below is the code I used to generate this table.

```
select flag,random_group, count(random_group) as freq
from
     (select case when rand_num >= 0 and rand_num<=0.053 then 1
                  when rand_num > 0.053 and rand_num <= 0.097 then 2
                  when rand_num > 0.097 and rand_num <= 0.142 then 3
                  when rand_num > 0.142 and rand_num <= 0.189 then 4
                  when rand_num > 0.189 and rand_num <= 0.234 then 5 end random_group, flag
       from
            (SELECT dbms_random.value(0,1) AS rand_num, 
                    rownum as at_row_num, 'CTR' as flag
             FROM abc 
             WHERE rownum <= 1000)
 union all
       select case when rand_num >= 0 and rand_num<=0.053 then 1
                   when rand_num > 0.053 and rand_num <= 0.097 then 2
                   when rand_num > 0.097 and rand_num <= 0.142 then 3
                   when rand_num > 0.142 and rand_num <= 0.189 then 4
                   when rand_num > 0.189 and rand_num <= 0.234 then 5 end random_group, flag
        from
            (SELECT dbms_random.value(0,1) AS rand_num, 
                    rownum as at_row_num, 'TRT' as flag
             FROM def 
             WHERE rownum <= 1000)
      )
group by flag, random_group
order by flag,random_group;
```

How can I fix this to get correct p value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stats_crosstab()` calculates the values based on the *detailed* rows not the *summary* rows.

In other words, where you have:

```
FLAG    RANDOM_GROUP    count
CTR          1            53
```

The function is expecting 53 rows with the combination of `CTR`/`1`, not one row with a count of 53.